# Crystal Report 13.2 getting field name is unknown error on IIS 8 hosted application ASP.NET

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-server-2012-r2

I have application which uses Crystal Report 13.2 for reporting purpose.
On local machine every thing works fine but after hosting application on server, it stops working.
My production server OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS is 8.5.
After hosting,it shows error if I try to load that report.:

> This field name is not known. Details: errorKind

Can any one suggest what the issue can be?

Comment: do you have the valid database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have the correct Crystal Reports version running on the serve side.  You can download it from [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) if you need it.

Second, change on the server side the "C:\Windows\Temp\" folder permissions to **read** and **write** for the **IIS_IUSRS** and **read & execute** for the **IUSR** group

[image: IIS_IUSRS Permissions over C:\Windows\Temp]
[image: IUSR Permissions over C:\Windows\Temp]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks... It works for me with  enabling 32 bit application for application pool.

Comment: One more issue I am facing with crystal report. The data is not being displayed in report viewer control. what can be the issue?

Comment: If it is working on your computer but not on the server, the only thing I can think of is the path where you have the report file .rpt is not found.  In my code I use the `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/YourRptFileNameHere.rpt");` to get the path then load it onto the ReportDocument Load function.  Also on your ASPX page make check the path under `<Report FileName="..\App_Data\YourRptFileNameHere.rpt"></Report>`.  If your report file is under a folder, like mine is under the App_Data folder, you need those `~` and `..` characters in front of the path respectively.

Comment: It is workig now. Issue was 'bobj' is undefined.It was due to missing path of crv.js. It is resolved now. Thanks :)